# how to remove duplicate value from option in react js?

Tags: reactjs

Code:-

```
<select id="lang" value={comment.ChannelName} autoFocus
                                        className="btn_primary" onChange={e => setPlayer(e.target.value, comment.idx)} >
                                        <option value="select">{comment.ChannelName}</option>
                                        {selectedData.map((val) => {
                                            // setCHANNEL = val;
                                            //console.log("val", val)
                                            return (
                                                <>

                                                    {
                                                        val.map((val1, inde) => {   
                                                                                                                 
                                                            return (
                                                                <option value={val1 ? val1 : ""}>{val1}</option>
                                                               
                                                        )
                                                        })
                                                    }


                                                </>
                                            )
                                        })
                                        }

                                    </select>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Showing duplicate value in option i have api like this:-

```
{
    "Clips": [
        {
            "AutoPlayMode": true,
            "ClipName": "Evernote Hacked, Time t_STRA005R",
            "Status": 1,
            "ChannelName": "A",
        }
  ],
    "Players": "A,B"
}
```

i when channelName A is selected option doesn't repeat the players in option as on B also
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA7hq.png

Comment: You should put a bit more effort in formatting the code in your question... remove some spaces/tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove redundant value from the second array before looping

```js
    
const removeRedundant = (array) => {
return array.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return array.indexOf(item) == pos;
})

}

return(
...
<select id="lang" value={comment.ChannelName} autoFocus className="btn_primary" onChange={(e) => setPlayer(e.target.value, comment.idx)}>
      <option value="select">{comment.ChannelName}</option>
      {selectedData.map((val) => {
        // setCHANNEL = val;
        //console.log("val", val)
        return (
          <>
            {removeRedundant([...val, comment.ChannelName]).map((val1, inde) => {
              return <option value={val1}>{val1}</option>;
            })}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </select>
)
```